# Golang with React Router?

Tags: go, reactjs, react-router

**How do I use React Router with Go?**

---

For example,

I have this in Go:

```
Echo.Get("/*", *handler which return page with ReactRouter*)
```

And this in React Router:

```
React.render((
<Router history={History.createHistory()}>
    <Route name="index" path="/" component={Main}>
        <Route name="users" path="/users" component={Users}>
            <Route name="user" path="/user/:userId" component={User} />
        </Route>
        <Route path="*" component={NotFound} />
    </Route>
</Router>
), document.body)
```

But I keep getting the index (/) page. All routes behave the same ('/', '/users', '/user/qwe', etc.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to render different routes with new bindings, or handle that binding specifically in your handler function and read out the request object's information.

```
Echo.Get("/user/:id", getUser)
Echo.Get("/users", listUsers)
Echo.Get("/*", catchAllRemainingCalls)
```

Hope this helps. Good luck!